# Browser switch handle Phantomjs Issue

Tags: selenium, testing, phantomjs, protractor, cucumberjs

I use protractor with cucumber and whenever there is a need to switch between browser tabs with phantomjs it just hangs without any error message. However the same step works fine with Chrome browser. Why is that? My step is as follows

```
this.Then(/^the page url hash should be "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        newWindowHandle = handles[2];
        browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
            expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.contain(arg1).and.notify(callback);
        });
    });
```

Comment: "We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor. There are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving differently from real browsers." http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/browser-support

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently the issue was with `callback`. When i modified the above code slightly it works like a charm even in phantomjs!

```
this.Then(/^the page url hash should be "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
       browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            newWindowHandle = handles[2];
            browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
                expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.contain(arg1);
            });
        });
        callback();

  });
```